# Unable to resolve a simple If-Else Function error in R

Tags: r

I am just trying to gain some knowledge about how to write functions in R. I created a simple `If-else` function which basically takes numerical input in function call.

If user gives `n=1`, iris dataframe is to be created and for any other number `mtcars`.

```
df1<-iris
df2<-mtcars
run<-function(n){
  if(n==1){
   data1<-df1
  } else {
    data1<-df2
  }
}

run(1)
```

But somehow this is just not working. I am missing something here.

Comment: You need to return the result of your function

Comment: use `return(data1)` or `data <- run(1)` , then check `data`

Answer (score 1):

What @C_Z_ said

```
df1<-iris
df2<-mtcars
run<-function(n, df1, df2){
  if(n==1){
   data1<-df1
  } else {
    data1<-df2
  }
return(data1)
}
```

Comment: You should also use `run <- function(n, df1, df2){` so that the function incorporates all of the objects explicitly.